# Remember form input using public var

Tags: php

Im trying to save form input after submitting the form, I tried this:

```
public $username;
public function loginForm() {
    $this->login = 
    "<form action='' method='post'>" .
    "<input id=first_name type=text class=validate name=username value=$username>" .

    if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && (empty($_POST["username"]))) {
        $this->username = $_POST["username"];
```

It still says that variable username is not defined, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: It checks if it isset then checks if its empty? and if it is empty then it stores the empty variable?, and if its not empty then what

Comment: @Richard I have the same `$this->username = $_POST["username"];` in the else block

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by putting the var inside the function:

```
public function displayLogin() {
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing some quotes here:

```
public $username;
public function loginForm() {
  $this->login = 
  '<form action="" method="post">' .
  '<input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" name="username" value="' . $username . '">' .

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && (empty($_POST["username"]))) {
    $this->username = $_POST["username"];
```

Comment: No, this is when creating a form outside PHP, the form I made is still in the PHP code

Comment: HTML-attributes always need quotes, no matter where you create them.You should post the whole code by the way, not just partial stuff.

Comment: This is not true, you would need them in the following example: `"<form action='' method='post'>"` because doing: `"<form action= method=post>"` would cause the HTML to read it like `action ="method=post"` but you can write classes like `class=classname` when creating the form inside PHP code

Comment: This is not a PHP-issue. I checked it again, it can work without quotes, but it's bad style and I wouldn't guarantee that every browser is able to parse it.